# RSA шифрование на C#

Tags: c#, .net, rsa

Хочу сделать простую шифровку алгоритмом RSA встроенными в .Net средствами. Как я это вижу:

1. Создаем объект RSA.
2. Из него получаем открытый и приватный ключи, сохраняем их.
3. Зашифровываем сообщение при помощи открытого ключа.
4. Зашифрованное в п.3 сообщение можем расшифровать при помощи приватного ключа.

Набросал по-быстрому демо для этого, в нем в **textBox1** находится текст, который я хочу зашифровать, по клику на **button1** происходит шифрование и результат помещается в **textBox2**; в **textBox3**, соответственно, мы можем поместить зашифрованное сообщение, а по нажатию на **button2** расшифровать его и увидеть результат в **textBox4**.

Исходный код (методы RSAEn(-De)crypt взял с сайта MSDN):

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        RSAParameters privateKey;
        RSAParameters publicKey;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            //Пункт 1
            RSACryptoServiceProvider RSA = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
            //Пункт 2
            privateKey = RSA.ExportParameters(true);
            publicKey = RSA.ExportParameters(false);
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            UnicodeEncoding byteConverter = new UnicodeEncoding();
            byte[] input = byteConverter.GetBytes(textBox1.Text);
            byte[] output;
            //Пункт 3
            output = RSAEncrypt(input, publicKey, false);

            textBox2.Text = byteConverter.GetString(output);
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            UnicodeEncoding byteConverter = new UnicodeEncoding();
            byte[] input = byteConverter.GetBytes(textBox3.Text);
            byte[] output;
            //Пункт 4
            output = RSADecrypt(input, privateKey, false);

            textBox4.Text = byteConverter.GetString(output);
        }

        static public byte[] RSAEncrypt(byte[] DataToEncrypt, RSAParameters RSAKeyInfo, bool DoOAEPPadding)
        {
                //Create a new instance of RSACryptoServiceProvider.
                RSACryptoServiceProvider RSA = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();

                //Import the RSA Key information. This only needs
                //toinclude the public key information.
                RSA.ImportParameters(RSAKeyInfo);

                //Encrypt the passed byte array and specify OAEP padding.  
                //OAEP padding is only available on Microsoft Windows XP or
                //later.  
                return RSA.Encrypt(DataToEncrypt, DoOAEPPadding);
        }

        static public byte[] RSADecrypt(byte[] DataToDecrypt, RSAParameters RSAKeyInfo, bool DoOAEPPadding)
        {
            //Create a new instance of RSACryptoServiceProvider.
            RSACryptoServiceProvider RSA = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();

            //Import the RSA Key information. This needs
            //to include the private key information.
            RSA.ImportParameters(RSAKeyInfo);

            //Decrypt the passed byte array and specify OAEP padding.  
            //OAEP padding is only available on Microsoft Windows XP or
            //later.  
            return RSA.Decrypt(DataToDecrypt, DoOAEPPadding);
        }
    }
```

Шифрует он всё нормально, но при дешифровке выдает **CryptographicException**, "Дополнительные сведения: Параметр задан неверно." Гугление ошибки результатов не дало. Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ошибка находится в **byteConverter**, ошибка возникает из-за того, что конвертер преобразуя в строку и обратно изменяет количество байт.

Для того, чтобы избежать эту ошибку используйте лучше **Base64String**:

```
Convert.ToBase64String();
Convert.FromBase64String();
```

Это гарантирует сохранность байт.

Вот пример консольного приложения для проверки:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        RSACryptoServiceProvider RSA = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
        //Пункт 2
        privateKey = RSA.ExportParameters(true);
        publicKey = RSA.ExportParameters(false);

        UnicodeEncoding byteConverter = new UnicodeEncoding();
        string toEncrypt = "Hello, world";

        Console.WriteLine($"To encode: {toEncrypt}");

        byte[] encBytes = RSAEncrypt(byteConverter.GetBytes(toEncrypt), publicKey, false);

        string encrypt = byteConverter.GetString(encBytes);
        Console.WriteLine("Encrypt str: " + encrypt);
        Console.WriteLine("Encrypt bytes: " + string.Join(", ", encBytes));

        byte[] decBytes = RSADecrypt(encBytes, privateKey, false);

        Console.WriteLine("Decrypt str: " + byteConverter.GetString(decBytes));
        Console.WriteLine("Decrypt bytes: " + string.Join(", ", byteConverter.GetBytes(encrypt)));

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```