# Проблема с RSA шифрованием

Tags: c#, windows, криптография, rsa

В [одном](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/661426/rsa-%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0-c) из ответов на вопрос по поводу `rsa` шифрования был дан код, который пытаюсь запустить.
Собственно, мой код выглядит следующим образом:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
class Program
{
    static public byte[] RSAEncrypt(byte[] DataToEncrypt, RSAParameters RSAKeyInfo, bool DoOAEPPadding)
    {

        RSACryptoServiceProvider RSA = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
        RSA.ImportParameters(RSAKeyInfo);
        return RSA.Encrypt(DataToEncrypt, DoOAEPPadding);
    }

    static public byte[] RSADecrypt(byte[] DataToDecrypt, RSAParameters RSAKeyInfo, bool DoOAEPPadding)
    {

        RSACryptoServiceProvider RSA = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
        RSA.ImportParameters(RSAKeyInfo);

        return RSA.Decrypt(DataToDecrypt, DoOAEPPadding);
    }


public static void Main()
    {
        RSAParameters privateKey;
        RSAParameters publicKey;

        RSACryptoServiceProvider RSA = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();

        privateKey = RSA.ExportParameters(true);
        publicKey = RSA.ExportParameters(false);

        UnicodeEncoding byteConverter = new UnicodeEncoding();
        string toEncrypt = "Hello, world";

        Console.WriteLine("To encode: ",toEncrypt);

        byte[] encBytes = RSAEncrypt(byteConverter.GetBytes(toEncrypt), publicKey, false);

        string encrypt = byteConverter.GetString(encBytes);
        Console.WriteLine("Encrypt str: " + encrypt);
        Console.WriteLine("Encrypt bytes: " + string.Join(", ", encBytes));

        byte[] decBytes = RSADecrypt(encBytes, privateKey, false);

        Console.WriteLine("Decrypt str: " + byteConverter.GetString(decBytes));
        Console.WriteLine("Decrypt bytes: " + string.Join(", ", byteConverter.GetBytes(encrypt)));

        Console.ReadKey();
    } 

}
}
```

Компилируется без ошибок, но при запуске даже не выводит `Hello, World`. Помогите найти ошибку, `c#` только начал изучать.

Comment: А запустить и в дебаге пошагово пройтись?

Comment: В дебагере вывод есть, как ни странно. В обычном режиме - нет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Console.WriteLine("To encode: ",toEncrypt); // !=  ","
```

Лишняя запятая :)

***Должно быть:***

```
Console.WriteLine("To encode: " + toEncrypt);  // +
```

*Надеюсь помог!*

---

**Использование:**

- Полный код:

  ```
  using System;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.Linq;
  using System.Security.Cryptography;
  using System.Text;
  using System.Threading.Tasks;

  namespace ConsoleApplication1
  {
   class Program
    {
      static public byte[] RSAEncrypt(byte[] DataToEncrypt, RSAParameters RSAKeyInfo, bool DoOAEPPadding)
      {

          RSACryptoServiceProvider RSA = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
          RSA.ImportParameters(RSAKeyInfo);
          return RSA.Encrypt(DataToEncrypt, DoOAEPPadding);
      }

      static public byte[] RSADecrypt(byte[] DataToDecrypt, RSAParameters RSAKeyInfo, bool DoOAEPPadding)
      {

          RSACryptoServiceProvider RSA = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
          RSA.ImportParameters(RSAKeyInfo);

          return RSA.Decrypt(DataToDecrypt, DoOAEPPadding);
      }


      public static void Main()
      {
          RSAParameters privateKey;
          RSAParameters publicKey;

          RSACryptoServiceProvider RSA = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();

          privateKey = RSA.ExportParameters(true);
          publicKey = RSA.ExportParameters(false);

          UnicodeEncoding byteConverter = new UnicodeEncoding();
          string toEncrypt = "Hello, world";

          Console.WriteLine("To encode: " + toEncrypt);

          byte[] encBytes = RSAEncrypt(byteConverter.GetBytes(toEncrypt), publicKey, false);

          string encrypt = byteConverter.GetString(encBytes);
          Console.WriteLine("Encrypt str: " + encrypt);
          Console.WriteLine("Encrypt bytes: " + string.Join(", ", encBytes));

          byte[] decBytes = RSADecrypt(encBytes, privateKey, false);

          Console.WriteLine("Decrypt str: " + byteConverter.GetString(decBytes));
          Console.WriteLine("Decrypt bytes: " + string.Join(", ", byteConverter.GetBytes(encrypt)));

          Console.ReadKey();
      }

    }
  }
  ```
- Вывод

[image: Вывод]

Comment: Все равно не выводит ничего. Тихо висит в диспетчере задач

Comment: Я запустил ваш код (с исправлением @Brave_Lime):
https://yadi.sk/i/pEcmNsxa3J6GfX  
Вроде все работает.

Comment: @IvanKramarchuk Благодарю :)

Comment: Brave_Lime, благодарю, работает. Проблема была, скорее всего в студии. Перезапустил - пишет что не может найти компоненты и просит переустановить. Запустил в SharpDevelop - работает.

Comment: Рад помочь, Удачи Вам в обучении!